# How much transaction fees are taken by bitcore for API use?

Tags: transaction-fees, sending, bitcore

If I am using the [API of bitcore.io](https://bitcore.io/api) and create transactions, how much transaction fees are taken by Bitcore?

I couldn't find any description in their documentation.

Comment: I've edited the tags, please note that Bitcoin Core and bitcore are two separate projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcore is open source software provided at no charge, so there is no fee you have to pay to the BitCore software authors.

When creating a Bitcoin transaction, it is highly recommend that you pay a fee to Bitcoin miners to encourage them to include your transaction in a block.  How much fee you pay is optional, and there are a number of [fee estimation services](https://p2sh.info/dashboard/db/fee-estimation?panelId=5&fullscreen&orgId=1&from=now-7d&to=now) that will recommend a fee for you.  See also other questions on Bitcoin StackExchange for more information about transaction fees in general.